# bitnami wamp how to install multiple php version

Tags: wamp

Anyone know how to install multiple php version in one bitnami WAMP system?
I would like to switch between 5.3 and 5.4 perhaps also 5.5, I can't Google any relevant tutorial about how to do it.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from bitnami forum,

We don't support to have more than one PHP version in the same stack. BTW, if you go to: Bitnami Wamp download , you will find three versions:

5.4.23-0 -> PHP 5.4
5.3.28-0 -> PHP 5.3
5.5.7-0 Dev -> PHP 5.5

You are able to have as much stacks as you want installed on your machine. The only thing, is that you will need to assign different ports to HTTP and MYSQL (for example: 80, 81 and 82), but the installer will ask you about it.

Best regards!